# ffmpeg cannot generate thumbnail

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to generate 10 .jpeg thumbs out of a video file. Most of the time it works fine but for some files (a 55seconds .mp4 for example) I get only the first 4 out of 10 captures, for the rest I get this error:
*Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)*

The command I use to convert is this one
`ffmpeg -ss 16 -i /path/source.mp4 -y -f image2 -t 0.001 -s 320*240 /path/thumb4.jpg`
where -ss value is a multiple of 4 and from 20 it stops working.

Command line full output:

```
`# ffmpeg -ss 77 -i /path/source.mp4 -y -f image2 -t 0.001 -s 320*240 /path/thumb7.jpg  
ffmpeg version git-2013-02-25-b8f6912 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers  
  built on Feb 25 2013 15:18:21 with gcc 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)  
  configuration: --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl  
  libavutil      52. 17.103 / 52. 17.103  
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100  
  libavformat    54. 63.100 / 54. 63.100  
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103  
  libavfilter     3. 41.100 /  3. 41.100  
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100  
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102  
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100  
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/path/source.mp4':  
  Metadata:  
    major_brand     : mp42  
    minor_version   : 19529845  
    compatible_brands: mp42isom  
    creation_time   : 2013-03-20 21:45:43  
  Duration: 00:02:04.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 605 kb/s  
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s  
    Metadata:  
      creation_time   : 2013-03-20 21:45:43  
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler  
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 40:33 DAR 20:11], 983 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc  
    Metadata:  
      creation_time   : 2013-03-20 21:45:43  
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler  
Output #0, image2, to '/path/thumb7.jpg':  
  Metadata:  
    major_brand     : mp42  
    minor_version   : 19529845  
    compatible_brands: mp42isom  
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.100  
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 320x240 [SAR 15:11 DAR 20:11], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc  
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-20 21:45:43  
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler  
Stream mapping:  
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mjpeg)  
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help  
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A      
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -inf%  
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `-t 0.001` you might end up exporting nothing. This is not the correct way of saying that you only need one frame. The `-t` option takes either seconds or a timestamp in the `HH:MM:SS.mmm` format.

Here's what should work:

```
ffmpeg -ss 16 -i /path/source.mp4 -frames:v 1 -s 320x240 /path/thumb4.jpg
```

Note that the `-f image2` option is not needed as the correct output format will be chosen anyway.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately I work on an adult-oriented project thus the only strange working examples are adult. Anyway, per your suggestion I tried converting the MP4 file to another MP4 file and I got an error: Truncating packet of size 3544 to 682
[h264 @ 0x6784e0] AVC: nal size 3534
[h264 @ 0x6784e0] no frame!
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Operation not permitted
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x676040] stream 1, offset 0x8ffccb: partial file
3IgLCrIR37np070SlwOu.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: That means my test file is broken?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's a decoding error due to a malformatted stream – no idea if that's easy to repair though.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I run ffmpeg from a BASH script, are you aware of a (simple) way of letting BASH script know that ffmpeg failed with an error so I can cover this option as well?

Comment: If you run `ffmpeg -y -loglevel quiet -i input.mp4 … && echo "yay" || echo "nay"` this should catch errors, e.g. print `nay` on a failed command.

Comment: I tested this and doesn't seem to work, any idea why?

Comment: It worked for me. What happens? Does it always echo the same thing (if so, what)? If `ffmpeg` encounters any error it'll stop and exit in such a way that you can catch it from the shell.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8059/discussion-between-alex-flo-and-slhck)